# Can I delete the newly created but unused universal analytics property when upgrading to Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, upgrade, google-analytics-4

I've upgraded to GA4 and kept my UA GA. The upgrade created two new properties: one with a new UA code and another one without. Of course the new property with the new UA doesn't get any traffic since I didn't add it to the site.

I managed to connect the original GA account to the GA4 property that doesn't have a UA code, but even if it says "connected" and the GA4 shows some traffic data, the data is not the same between the GA and the GA4. For example, real-time report in GA4 is always in 0 even if I have traffic in the real-time report in GA.

Does anybody know if I should set up the UA code of the GA4 new property in the site anyway? Can I delete the UA GA4 property? (!) Is it the reason why the data that the GA4 property is not the same as in the GA original account?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you possibly created a new property as opposed to upgrading an existing UA property. Upgrading doesnt create a new UA property, just a GA4 property to work in tandem with the existing UA property.

Few things going on here. Regarding real time reporting, the two property types work differently to each other. Real time reporting for GA4 batches hits, it does not send them through the same way as Universal GA, so they wont appear in the real time reports the same way as each other.

I would delete the extra UA property that was created in error that is not installed on the website.

Have you edited your tracking code on the website to configure it to take the existing UA tracker and the new GA4 tracker into account?